# Subjunctive Mood while using present tense

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, subjunctives, present-subjunctive

**The Girl seems as if she is about to faint.**

Source: Heat Lightening (PLAY)

It is I think general rule to use past tense to talk about an unreal situation of the present event. But contrary to the canonical law of grammar this sentence has the usage of present tense in both clauses to describe a hypothetical situation. Does this sentence convey the same sense as, The Girl seemed as if she were about to faint,? If not, then what is the actual definition of this sentence? If yes, then why do we use past tense to talk about an unreal situation?

Comment: This isn't an unreal situation, just an assessment of the girl's appearance (like a person on the point of fainting).

Comment: It's a matter of present time vs past time meaning, not modality. There's no subjunctive clause here.